# Can I pass a pointer to a derived-class field to the superconstructor if the superconstructor doesn't use that pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, superclass

If I have a derived class, I know that the fields aren't instantiated yet when the superconstructor is called.  But, can I pass a pointer to one such field (obtained with &field) to the superconstructor if I know that the superconstructor is not going to dereference the pointer?

Particularly, I want to know whether the call to &field will behave properly and point to the section of memory which will eventually contain that field.

Comment: This is described in [basic.life]/5, an extract: "Before the lifetime of an object has started but after the storage which the object will occupy has been
allocated or, after the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the object occupied is
reused or released, any pointer that refers to the storage location where the object will be or was located
may be used but only in limited ways." (N.B. during the call to the base class' ctor, the data members of the derived class are not "constructed" yet, so their lifetime might not have started.)

Comment: Another relevant part is [class.cdtor]/3 "To form a pointer to (or
access the value of) a direct non-static member of an object `obj`, the construction of `obj` shall have started
and its destruction shall not have completed, otherwise the computation of the pointer value (or accessing
the member value) results in undefined behavior."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, although actually doing this would be questionable at best.

Comment: Thanks, I just realized actually my super-constructor does dereference the pointer so I'll have to do this a different way, but it's still good to know for future reference